# After upgrade to 4.6, should I get "No available releases found warning" in Reports->Available updates?

Tags: 4.6.0, upgrade

In the Drupal menu item "Reports->Available updates", I get the below.  Is this normal or is there something I could / should do to fix this?

civicrm 4.6.0                                     No available releases found
Includes:
Enabled: CiviCRM, CiviCRM Contact Reference Field, CiviCRM Theme, CiviEngage, CiviGroup Roles Sync, CiviMember Roles Sync
Disabled: CiviCRM OG Sync, CiviCRM Rules Integration

Answer (score 4):

The 'no available releases found' is due to fact that CiviCRM is not distributed through Drupal.org's release infrastructure. The other enabled and disabled modules seem normal. If this doesn't address your concerns could you be more specific about what you are concerned about?