# How to disable Drupal's module update check for CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal

A previous question asked about the "No available releases found" warning that Drupal shows in the Modules Update page. An answer said that this is caused by the fact that CiviCRM doesn't use Drupal's release infrastructure.

[Previous thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/510/after-upgrade-to-4-6-should-i-get-no-available-releases-found-warning-in-repo)

In any case, Drupal still emails me with the warning that "There was a problem checking available updates for your modules or themes."

Given that I like my sites to run without errors, the OCD part of me cringes at this. How might I correct this so that Drupal and I are happy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options:

- CiviCRM could use Drupal's infrastructure to ship CiviCRM downloads. Current CiviCRM / Drupal development process prevents this, and that's a much bigger topic and best discussed outside of this SO question!
- CiviCRM could somehow suppress the update notifications from the Drupal update status page. This would hide the warning, but arguably be a worse outcome. I don't think this would deliver what you want.
- CiviCRM could supply a project feed to match the existing Drupal.org infrastructure, so that Drupal can check that alternate feed URL for updates.

IMO the last option is the best balance of outcomes - it could provide accurate update notifications to Drupal-oriented administrators who might not see the in-app warnings in CiviCRM. There's a JIRA proposing this over at [CRM-15769](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15769).

Comment: Thank you. I will take that as "This annoys others too, however there is no current sensible solution or workaround. We all just have to live with it."

Comment: I think Dr Seuss captured the essence of many commonly owned things, including open source, when the Onceler said: *"Unless someone like you cares a whole awful lot, Nothing is going to get better. It's not."* You don't have to tackle this! I haven't, and I filed that issue a few years ago. But it won't get better until *someone* does :D